# If $f(x)＝\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ is bounded and convergent in $[0,1)$ and $a_n >0$, then $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Let $f(x)＝$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n(x∈\mathbb{R})$  be power series
> and $a_n$ be positive real number. Suppose $f(x)$ converge when $ ｜x｜＜1$,  and $f$ is bounded in $[0,1)$, then
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n $$
> converges.

My try:

$\{ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \}$ is obviously monotonic increasing, if I could prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n $ is bounded, I can finish the proof. But I cannot find upper bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\sum a_n$ were divergent, then for any $M>0$ one could find $N$ such that
$\sum_{n=0}^{n=N} a_n > M$. Then for $x$ sufficiently close to 1 one would have
$\sum_{n=0}^{n=N} a_nx^{n} > M/2$. Since coefficients are non-negative this would imply that $f(x) > M/2$ for such $x$, hence $f$ is unbounded on [0,1].

Comment: Could you tell me why $Σanx^n＞M/2$ ?(why $M/2$ ?)

Comment: @Nekojiru the polynomial function $\sum_{n = 0}^{n = N} a_n x^n$ is continuous on $[0, 1].$

Comment: @Nekojin, Because $\sum_{n=0}^{n=N}a_nx^{n}$ is continuous function so its limit when $x->1^{-}$ is the same as its value there which is $\sum_{n=0}^{n=N}$. In words, for $x$ sufficiently close to 1 the value has to be bigger than $M/2$

Comment: @Why $M/2$? Can we use $M$?

Comment: You can use anything less than $M$, for example $.098*M$. I chose $M/2$ arbitrary (but still less than M)